# Setting environment variable for different tabs using gnome-terminal

Tags: scripts, gnome-terminal

In order to set up a number of applications, I'm trying to do something similar as:

```
gnome-terminal \
--tab "app1" --working-directory=dir1 -e "export app=1 & npm start" \
--tab "app2" --working-directory=dir2 -e "export app=2 & npm start" \
--tab "app3" --working-directory=dir3 -e "export app=3 & npm start" \
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error: Failed to execute child process "export" (No such file or directory)
```

Does someone know how and if it is possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the commands as part of bash or another shell.

Try this:

```
gnome-terminal \
--tab "app1" -e "bash -c \"cd app1; export app=app1; npm run start\""
```

and add similar for others.